# jQuery timer

Tags: jquery

Есть в диве n ссылок, по `document.ready` нужно их прокликать по порядку, но с задержкой в 3 секунды м/у кликом.

```
$('div a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
$('div a').each(function(){
    setTimeout($(this).click(),3000);
});
```

Не работает. Если через `setInterval`, то кликает с интервалом, но каждый раз сразу по 4 ссылки. т.е. выводится 4 серии алертов из 4-х алертов.

```
 <div>
        <a href="#">Alert 1</a>
        <a href="#">Alert 2</a>
        <a href="#">Alert 3</a>
        <a href="#">Alert 4</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: А не подскажешь какой в этом смысл? Так ради интереса.

Comment: Ну вот такая задачка) смысла может и нет, но решить надо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// $('div a').click( ... );

var timeout = 0; 
$('div a').each(function() { 
    var self = $(this); 
    setTimeout(function() { self.click(); }, timeout += 3000); 
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает